# Factorial Number System with Repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, number-systems

Good Day

I know about how [Factorial Number System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) is useful to find permutations and also find the the index of a permutation.

For example, permutation $[1, 3, 4, 0, 2]$ has index ($0$ - based) $1 \cdot 4! + 2 \cdot 3! + 2 \cdot 2! + 0 \cdot 1! + 0 \cdot 1! = 40$ where the constant is the index ($0$ - based) of the number in the *unused* numbers.

However, what if the arrangement contains repetitions. Consider $[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]$. Now arrangement $[2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]$ should have index $\frac{6!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!} - 1 = 89$, but if I go the usual way and consider the index in only the distinct unused numbers, I get $2 \cdot 5! + 2 \cdot 4! + \cdots$ which is already larger than $89$. Even doing $2 \cdot \frac{120}{2 \cdot 2} + 2 \cdot \frac{24}{2 \cdot 2} + 1 \cdot \frac{6}{2} + 1 \cdot \frac{2}{2}$ gives $76$.

Thus, is there a simple way to extend this system for repetitions, so that given an array of possibly non-distinct numbers, I can find the lexicographic index of the arrangement and from the (lexicographic) index, find the arrangement **without casework**?

Thanks

Comment: $[2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]$ is the lexicographically maximal distinct permutation of $[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]$ so it is the last among the $90$ distinct permutations.

Comment: First step is to allocate a number for the positions of the $0$s (there are ${6 \choose 2} =15$ of these) and your example might give a value of $14$ zero-based.  Multiply this by ${4 \choose 2}=6$ and add to it a number for the positions of the $1$s once the $0$s are ignored (there are ${4 \choose 2} =6$ of these) and your example might give a value of $5$ zero-based.  So you get $14\times 6+5=89$

Comment: Once you split it like Henry suggested, you can use a method similar to [this](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/compindx.htm#comb) to encode the of positions of a particular digit to a number and vice versa.

Comment: @Henry Can you please elaborate your approach a bit? Thanks

Comment: If your multiset has $n_0$ $0$s, $n_1$ $1$s, $n_2$ $2$s, and $n_3$ $3$s then you want a number $p_0$ corresponding to the positions of the $0$s out of the ${n_0+n_1+n_2+n_3 \choose n_0}$ possibilities.  Then, ignoring the $0s$ you   you want a number $p_1$ for the positions of the $1$s out of the ${n_1+n_2+n_3 \choose n_1}$ possibilities;   ignoring the $0s$ and $1s$ you want a number $p_2$ for the positions of the $2$s out of the ${n_2+n_3 \choose n_2}$ possibilities; then there is a single remaining choice for the $3$s so $p_3=0$.

Comment: Your overall number is then $p_0 \frac{(n_1+n_2+n_3)!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!} +p_1 \frac{(n_2+n_3)!}{n_2!n_3!}+p_2 \frac{n_3!}{n_3!} +p_3$

Comment: Ohhh, I get it. We consider the least digit. We consider the "position" of the arrangement of this digit in the entire array. Then we multiply with the number of ways to permute the rest of the elements. Remove the occurrences of this digit from the array and repeat.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis In the given website, I hope the method is the method given under the 'Indexing Combinations' category. How does it work? Consider $[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]$ the position of $0$ is $2$ but the algorithm gives $\binom{3}{2} = 3$

Comment: @MangoPizza Those indexing/deindexing routines don't actually use lexicographical order cause I wanted the code to be simple and readable as possible. The order of the $\binom52$ combinations is $00xxx$, $0x0xx$, $x00xx$, $0xx0x$, $x0x0x$, $xx00x$, $0xxx0$, $x0xx0$, $xx0x0$, $xxx00$. It would be lexicographical if you reversed the order of the list and reversed the order of the array, but usually the actual order doesn't matter as long as indexing and de-indexing are exact inverses. It works by skipping over the $\binom{i}{r}$ entries on the list that don't have a $0$ in the $i$-th location.

Comment: @Henry Thank you. This tells how to find the index of the permutation. But how do we find the permutation given the index? I am thinking of greedy: The method will be to floor divide and find the index of the arrangement, subtract and repeat?

Comment: If you can read Python, you may enjoy my code [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115024/46655) for permutation indices that handles repetition.

Comment: I *think* both the ranking & unranking algorithms are O(n log n), but I wrote that code 5 years ago, and don't feel like analysing it right now. ;) Besides, the actual running times are affected by the amount of repetition that occurs, so analysing the time complexity purely in terms of n is a bit crude. It's probably more useful to do empirical tests with data that has a repetition probability matching the data you want to use it on.

Comment: @Henry Consider the multiset is $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. Now, the index of $[1, 2, 0, 3]$ according to your method is $2 \cdot 3! + 0 \cdot 2! + 0 \cdot 1! + 0 \cdot 0!$ = $12$. However, the actual answer is $8$. Am I mis-understanding your method?

Comment: I did not actually specify a code, though your interpretation of what I wrote seems reasonable.  In the same way $[2,0,3,1]$ could have given an index of $8$ and each pattern would give a unique index from $0$ through to $23$ as desired.

Comment: @Henry Can you please elaborate? The index of $[2, 0, 3, 1]$ is $13$, and with your method it is $1 \cdot 3! + 2 \cdot 2! + 0 \cdot 1! + 0 \cdot 0! = 10$. How did we get $8$?

Comment: Not thinking.  Perhaps I should have given $[2,0,1,3]$

Comment: @Henry So do you mean that your method of finding index does not give the index of a permutation in lexicographic order (But in some other order)? In this case, how to find the lexicographic index?

Comment: My original comment was about finding an index, not necessarily a lexicographic index

Comment: @Henry Oh ok. Any idea on how to find the lexicographic index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of a binary string can be found using the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system).

For example, $N=100=1100100_2$ can be considered as an element of the k-combination set $\binom{7}{3}$.

As such it can be written $\{6,5,2\}$, where each element is a set bit in $N$. We then have $100=2^6+2^5+2^2$.

Its (zero-based) index is then given by the formula:

$$\binom{6}{3}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{2}{1}=20+10+2=32$$

(There are $\binom{7}{3}=35$ in total.)

It works by examining each bit separately. For example, the formula states that there are exactly $\binom{6}{3}$ 3-combinations **before** the $6$, because $0111000 _2< 1000000_2$. Similarly there are $\binom{5}{2}$ 2-combinations before $0100000$, and so on. Therefore every $N$ has a unique representation.

For a permutation with repetition, a similar process can be used.

For example, consider $[3,2,2,0,3,1,3]$. We first break this into its components for each digit:

- $[3,-,-,-,3,-,3]$
- $[-,2,2,-,-,-,-]$
- $[-,-,-,-,-,1,-]$
- $[-,-,-,0,-,-,-]$

We follow a similar process as with the binary string for each component, and multiply by a positioning factor which is determined by its associated multinomial.

For example, the $3$ row becomes $\binom{6}{3}+\binom{2}{2}+\binom{0}{1}=20+1+0=21$.

The total number of permutations is $\frac{7!}{3!2!1!1!}=840$. The size of the 3-block is $\binom{7}{3}=35$, and so $\frac{840}{35}=24$ gives the multiplying factor.

The $2$ row is $\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{1}=5$ because it is nested into the 3-block. The multiplying factor is $\frac{24}{\binom{4}{2}}=4$.

After working out the last two rows, the index is:

$$21\cdot24+5\cdot4+0\cdot2+0\cdot1=524$$.

Comment: Hi JMP, If I understand correctly, this is the same method as @Henry suggested. However, it does not seem to give the lexicographical ordering of a permutation as Henry mentioned in comments. Am I right or am I misunderstanding? Thanks

Comment: I haven't read Henry's method - this one is my own. It does return the lexicographical order, i.e. $3332210$ is last, $0122333$ is first, etc...

Comment: Hello, suggested corrections: 7!/3!2!1!1!=420, multiplying factor is therefore 12, which is 4!/2!1!1!. Result should be 21*12+5*2+0*2+0*1=262.